# JAVA BufferOverflowException, while keeping buffer capacity?

Tags: java, buffer-overflow, bytebuffer

So i have a method that creates an IntBuffer from an ByteBuffer:

```
public static IntBuffer directIntBuffer(int[]buffer){
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*buffer.length);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        IntBuffer ib = bb.asIntBuffer();
        ib.put(buffer).flip();
        return ib;
    }
```

In another class's constructor i'm initialising one of these IntBuffers and filling it up with a nested for loop:

**EDIT:** so this is my full constructor. I'm filling up the FloatBuffer FBVertices with the actual vertex coordinates and the IntBuffer IBVerticesIndex with the indices. Later down, i draw these using           GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, IBVerticesIndex);

```
public sphereHelper(float fRadius, int iSlices, int iStacks)

{  
    FBVertices = GLDrawHelper.directFloatBuffer(new float[iSlices*iStacks*4*3]); 
    FBVertices.clear();

    IBVerticesIndex = GLDrawHelper.directIntBuffer(new int[iSlices*iStacks*4]);
    IBVerticesIndex.clear();
    int index=0;




    float verticalDegreePerStack= (float)Math.PI/iStacks; //1*Pi because we only want the height of the sphere once (from -PI/2 to PI/2)
    float horizontalDegreePerSlice = 2.0f* (float)Math.PI/iSlices; //2*Pi because of unit circle/polar coordinates going once around the sphere

    for (int k=0; k< iStacks; k++)
    {
        //overall vertical angle
        float rho= (float)k*verticalDegreePerStack;
        //sinus of that angle
        float srho =(float) (Math.sin(rho));

        float crho = (float) (Math.cos(rho));

        //sinus and cosinus of vertical angle+ angle of 1 stack
        float srhodrho= (float) (Math.sin(rho + verticalDegreePerStack));
        float crhodrho = (float) (Math.cos(rho + verticalDegreePerStack));

        for (int j=0; j<iSlices;j++)
        {
            //overall angle along the horizontal border (0 degree at full 2*PI circle)
            float theta = (j==iSlices)? 0.0f : j*horizontalDegreePerSlice;
            //sinus and cosinus
            float stheta = (float)(-Math.sin(theta));
            float ctheta = (float)(Math.cos(theta));

            //coordinates of first vertex of current triangle
            float x=stheta*srho;
            float z=ctheta*srho;
            float y=crho;


            //put coordinates of first vertex into buffer
            FBVertices.put(new float[]{x*fRadius,y*fRadius,z*fRadius});

            //put index of first vertex of polygon in index array, increase index counter by one
            if (IBVerticesIndex.position()<IBVerticesIndex.capacity())
            {IBVerticesIndex.put(index);}
            index++;
            //second vertex
            x = stheta*srhodrho;
            z = ctheta*srhodrho;
            y = crhodrho;

            //put these coordinates into Buffer
            FBVertices.put(new float[] {x*fRadius,y*fRadius,z*fRadius});


             if (IBVerticesIndex.position()+2<IBVerticesIndex.capacity())
            {
            IBVerticesIndex.put(new int[] {index,index+1,index+2});}
            index++;

            System.out.println(IBVerticesIndex.position()+"/"+IBVerticesIndex.capacity());

        }
        IBVerticesIndex.flip();
        FBVertices.flip();

       }
    }
```

I get an BufferOverflowException, at this output:

> 4/400 8/400 12/400 16/400 20/400 24/400 28/400 32/400 36/400 40/400
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferOverflowException

So it is overflowing at a 10th of the buffers capacity?
I cleared() the buffer in the beginning so the position should be reset.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Unable to reproduce, I get `400/400` as output any time I run your code.

Comment: What type is IBVerticesIndex in your code (I simply declared it as `IntBuffer`) ... can you edit your post and include the surrounding code?  How are you getting those outputs exactly?  Oh your `println` is inside the inner loop, not where you put it in the example code. And you're missing some curly... please clean up that mess, it's obviously confusing at least one reader of your question :P  Still can't reproduce, I get all outputs from `4/400` to `400/400` in steps of 4.  Your problem is elsewhere.  What code did you omit between the declaration of `index` and the loops?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the mess. I cut out the presumably irrelevant parts as i'm trying to fill an OPENGL index buffer for vertices of a sphere here. You are right about the curly bracket, the println should be outside the loops.
I will update the question with mor of my code.

Comment: From the Buffer superclass, *`flip()` makes a buffer ready for a new sequence of channel-write or relative get operations: It sets the limit to the current position and then sets the position to zero.*  It also means you're overwriting data in the buffers every iteration of the outer loop, because the position is set to 0.  I sincerely doubt that's what you want in this constructor?

Comment: THATS IT! The flip() wasn't supposed to be within the loop. When you work with so much code you get blind for these little details.
Thanks to both of you.

Comment: BTW: From [`IntBuffer.order()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/IntBuffer.html#order--): *The byte order of an int buffer created by allocation or by wrapping an existing int array is the native order of the underlying hardware. The byte order of an int buffer created as a view of a byte buffer is that of the byte buffer at the moment that the view is created.*  So it seems that you could simplify the stuff a lot by simply [wrapping an `int` array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/IntBuffer.html#wrap-int:A-)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** +1 to Arjan's comment on the original question. I copied Don's code to my machine and it's working on Java 8, also get 400/400 as the output. Are you setting the `limit` elsewhere in the remarked-out code?

Have you read up on how the [Buffer superclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#limit()) works? Specifically, the class has a `limit` property which does not have a well documented initial value. Writing past the `limit` value throws a `BufferOverflowException`.

It seems to me that you want to use this `IntBuffer` like a primitive array, in which case in your initialization routine you need to set the `limit` to the `capacity` after the call to `flip()` which according to the docs resets the `limit` to the `mark`.

Comment: Not really to my observations. Requesting and comparing position()and capacity() shouldn't influence the pointer/limit right? I read that there is a write and a read mdoe on each ByteBuffer and that the limit is only equal the capacity when in write mode. The call .clear() should set it into write mode to my understanding. If it's not too much can you test the whole code and wheteher it's producing the same output?

Comment: I copied your new code over and I am getting similar output as you. Seems to hit 40/400 several times in my screen output. Still looking at it.

Comment: Found the problem, the flip() reset the buffer pointer each loop. Thanks!

Comment: Moving the code outside that next brace seems to work, as I get the 400/400 output now. One last note for you - allocating 400 `int` primitives means 1600 bytes. Depending on how complex your mesh ends up, you may consider using `unsigned short` instead to save some memory. Java doesn't offer this, but the Google Guava library does I believe.